# “Enchanté” vs “ravi de vous rencontrer”

Tags: salutations

I came across the phrase "ravie de vous rencontrer" on Lingq today and it made me wonder why not just say "Enchanté" when you want to say "pleased to meet you"?
Under what circumstances would you use the phrase "ravie de vous rencontrer"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Ravi de vous rencontrer" and "Enchanté" are very similar but "Enchanté" is a bit stronger, older and less formal.

"Enchanté" is more for someone you met in a casual way (friends of someone, parents of someone etc.)

As for "Ravi de vous rencontrer", it's a very formal way of saying hello. It's often use in work when you met a superior for the first time or in a job interview. And still, it depends of your work environment.

But in general, people just say "Salut" or "Bonjour", even if they met for the 1st time.

Answer (score 2):

"Ravi de vous rencontrer" or "Enchanté" can be used when you meet someone for the first time. "Ravi de vous rencontrer" seems a little bit cliché and precious. A lot of people in France use "enchanté" because it's simpler and more direct

Answer (score 0):

"Enchanté" is actually wrong according to etiquette and protocol and should be avoided as it isn't a full French sentence. Using it in very formal situations would make you look unaware of the rules. "Ravi de vous rencontrer" is a charming alternative and works in all situations.